# How to detect a duplicate contact when Inserting a new one?

Tags: android

For a Contacts backup app, I save all the information to a CSV file, and then I need to restore it back. It works great, however if I press restore twice, it duplicates all the contacts.

I tried the following code to remove duplicates, it does work but fails in certain cases.
Basically it fails when there is no explicit DISPLAY_NAME, for e.g. if a contact seems to only have a phone number and the DISPLAY_NAME is the phone number, or same for an email address. I cannot understand why it wont always work since it does seem that the DISPLAY_NAME field contains phonenumber/email address.

Here is the code that I used:

```
private boolean contactExists(String displayname, String emailstring, String phonestring){
           Cursor crsr = BA.applicationContext.getContentResolver().query(
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                   new String[] { "display_name", "_id"},                  
                   "display_name = ? ",
                   new String[] {displayname},
                   null);


           while (crsr.moveToNext()){
                HashMap m = new HashMap();
                for (int col = 0; col < crsr.getColumnCount(); col++) {
                  m.put(crsr.getColumnName(col), Integer.valueOf(col));
                }
               int id = crsr.getInt(((Integer)m.get("_id")).intValue());
               String emails = GetEmails(id);
               String phones = GetPhones(id);

               if (emails.contentEquals(emailstring) && phones.contentEquals(phonestring))
               {
                   crsr.close();
                   return true;
               }
           }
           crsr.close();
           return false;
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I tried with DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY with the same results.

However what I noticed is that, if I create the contacts on the same device/emulator, the duplicate is detected, when I re-restore the same contacts.
On going across devices, it seems that one reason it does not work is that at some point the special characthers are removed.
For e.g. the display name "John.Doe" is read from the CSV, but when it gets inserted, it becomes "John Doe". I cannot see where in the code the "." is ever stripped out.

Answer (score 1):

What happens depends on the version of Android the device is running. If the version is Honeycomb (3.0) or later, the contact will *always* have a name. The name field is DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY, and if there's no name in any of the raw contacts, this field is set to a phone number or email address.

It's hard to know exactly what's going on with your code, because I can't tell how you're calling contactExists in all cases. But my guess is that you're looking at DISPLAY_NAME, when you may want to look at DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY.

As a side comment, what you're trying to do here is fraught with peril. The contacts provider is a complex system, and backing it up to a CSV may cause a lot of problems down the road. A much better strategy is to run a sync between the contacts provider and the cloud-based Google Contacts app.

Comment: Thanks for replying Joe. I did read about DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY before posting, but I couldnt find how to retrieve it, I will try it, but if it doesnt work on GB (2.3) then I cannot use it. I simple query the DISPLAY_NAME and save it to CSV(with other fields) and then read it back on the restore. I do see facing many problems as you say, but I wanted to keep it simple. I used CSV to keep the data Human Readable and it needs to be synced to Dropbox rather than google contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code which finds duplicate contact. You need to pass the "NAME" as string and it will look for duplicate. It works in ICS but didn't check in GB, so basically you need to try your luck.

```
/**
     * @param name
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isContactExist(String name) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
            String[] projection = new String[] { PhoneLookup._ID,
                    PhoneLookup.LOOKUP_KEY };
            String selection = StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ?";
            String[] selectionArguments = { name };
            Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection,
                    selectionArguments, null);

            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    /*
                     * Log.i(TAG, "KEY = " + cursor.getString(cursor
                     * .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY)));
                     */
                    result = true;
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            result = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```